# How to resolve error with None type of soup.find table?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to get a table by using BeautifulSoap, and I faced error while using `find` method.

I want to get headers of table from here: https://stooq.pl/t/?i=513&v=1&l=1

The id of a table i interested in is `fth1`, and HTML looks like that:

```
<table class="fth1" id="fth1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
    <thead style="background-color:e9e9e9">
        <tr align="center">
            <th id="f13">
                <a href="t/?i=513&amp;v=1&amp;o=1">Symbol</a>
            </th>
            <th id="f13">
                <a href="t/?i=513&amp;v=1&amp;o=2">Nazwa</a>
            </th>
        ...
```

My python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
page = requests.get('https://stooq.pl/t/?i=513&v=1&l=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

table1 = soup.find('table', {'id': "fth1"})

headers = []
for i in table1.find_all('th'):
    title = i.text
    headers.append(title)

print(headers)
```

I got the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/.../script.py", line 25, in 
> for i in table1.find_all('th'):
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

I found that the variable `table1` has a type `None`.
I've tried use `html.parser` and `html5lib` instead of `lxml` but with no success.

What is wrong that I got such error?

Comment: Print soup first, you'll see it returns Javascript and not the HTML you see when inspecting via your browser

Comment: @Samt94 Thank you for your answer. Yes, you're right. It prints me a html with a big script. So then, do you have any idea how to get this table even though there is script?

Comment: try - `print([title.get_text() for title in soup.find_all('th', {'id': 'f13'})])`

Comment: Code works fine for me. Returns `['Symbol', 'Nazwa', 'Otwarcie', 'Max', 'Min', 'Kurs', 'Zmiana', 'Wolumen', 'Obrót', 'Data', '']`

Comment: @SergeyK It doesn't work. Still have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still scrape the site, in order to do so you need to copy your cookies/headers from your browser and inject them into the request. If you go to your Network tab on the browser, find the HTML document and inspect it or right click and copy as curl, you can then convert that to python.

Your request would then look something like this (but with your cookies):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cookies = {
    'cookie_uu': '',
    'privacy': '',
    'PHPSESSID': '',
    'uid': '',
    'cookie_user': '',
    '_ga': '',
    '_gid': '',
    '__gads': '',
    'FCCDCF': '',
    'FCNEC': '',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}

params = {
    'i': '513',
    'v': '1',
    'l': '1',
}

response = requests.get('https://stooq.pl/t/', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', {'id': "fth1"})

headers = [i.text for i in table.find_all('th')]
print(headers)
```

This returns:

```
['Symbol', 'Nazwa', 'Otwarcie', 'Max', 'Min', 'Kurs', 'Zmiana', 'Wolumen', 'Obrót', 'Data', '']
```

Comment: it doesn't make sense, all this does not affect the fetching of the page

Comment: Yes it does, a lot of websites require specific headers/cookies in order to get through, if I print the soup object of the inital code. I am returned with a javascript function, not the navigable html. In both my case and in the OPs case.

Comment: no in this case it useless, simple - `soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://stooq.pl/t/?i=513&v=1&l=1').text, 'lxml')
print([title.get_text() for title in soup.find_all('th', {'id': 'f13'})])` return same -  `['Symbol', 'Nazwa', 'Otwarcie', 'Max', 'Min', 'Kurs', 'Zmiana', 'Wolumen', 'Obrót', 'Data', '']`

Comment: And as I previously mentioned, that doesn't work for me or the OP. That returns: []
[Finished in 1.1s]

Comment: obv there is a problem with the versions. A simple curl without any headers gives a complete table

Comment: can you try this one - `print(' '.join(pd.read_html('https://stooq.pl/t/?i=513&v=1&l=1')[31].columns[:-1]))`  dont forget - `import pandas as pd`

Comment: @Samt94 I've tested your answer, and it's work well. The main disadvantage of your solution is that cookies can expire after some time, and I'll have to modify script with new param value. I copied only the `privacy` value from my cookies and this lead me to the main source of problem. I think, that when the script opens my webpage, it doesn't see the table but screen with information about cookies (check it on private tab). After dismiss the dialog, we'll see table. Maybe this is the reason why script failed without `privacy` param from cookie?